# Regex help needed after curl operation

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match regex with the following html response after an curl operation, if it displays

```
Results: Displaying 1 of 1 entries
```

then i have the following code set-up

```
$pos = strpos($response, 'Results: Displaying 1 of 1 entries');
```

and I use `if`($pos !== false)` in order to do stuff

however I need to also match conditions where I need to fine-tune search arguments if it will return an set of results (more then 1)

so something like `Results: Displaying 1 of X entries` where x is greater then 1

what regex expression may be used with strpos to match this condition

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use preg_match(): https://www.php.net/preg_match

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Your regex might be something like:

```
Results: Displaying 1 of ([0-9]+) entries
```

To check if the number is greater than 1, you'll have to compare the first captured group, which can be found in the array &$matches[1] (the third parameter, see php documentation).

Comment: You probably mean `[0-9]+` instead of `(0-9)+`